# Get ppid in windows with python

Tags: python, windows, process

I have a list of processes pid that are running, and I want to kill the children, but not the process itself.

I want to iterate all processes and get the ppid to compare to the pids I have to know if I have to kill that process.

I used psutil, but it has dependencies I do not want to depend on.

Right now, I have been able to iterate all processes by doing this:

```
process_list = os.popen('TASKLIST').read()
 for p in process_list:
  print p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a DLL of some sort since Windows does not have an intrinsic API that yields PPID. If you don't use psutil, you'll have to write your own.

The Python support for finding child processes  is added by the system dependent library call `psutil_get_ppid` in [process_info.c](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/psutil/arch/mswindows/process_info.c#sl_svn7eb9b863271e831d400fd28e9153278a00b056cd_248) of module [psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/).

Comment: That's what I thought. I modified my application installation process to execute the precompiled version of psutil (since the pip install was not working)